# Invalid version '1.1build1' on package distro-info

Tags: python, github-actions, workflow, poetry

Возникла ошибка: устанавливаю пакеты c помощью poetry в github workflow. Используется ubuntu-latest. Poetry установлен, добавлен в PATH, команда вызывается в одной директории с pyproject.toml.

**Текст ошибки**:

```
Invalid version '1.1build1' on package distro-info
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

**workflow**:

```
. . .
- name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        cd backend/users
        poetry config virtualenvs.create ${{env.POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE}} # false
        poetry install --no-root
. . .
```

Comment: 1.1build1 - это версия вашего проекта или какой-то зависимости?

Comment: И еще, как poetry устанавливаете?

Answer (score 0):

у меня была та же проблема.
Я обновил poetry и pipenv, и прошло вроде как.